# How to prevent a web app from calling System.exit() in WSO2?

Tags: wso2

WSO2 folks,

I'm looking at WSO2 Application Server, and I created a web app to invoke System.exit(), which brings down the whole app server. I'm asking because the apps from multiple tenants could be running on the same Application Server, and we need to prevent a malicous tenant from killing the whole JVM.

My first thought was to use a SecurityManager to restrict the access, but I'm not sure where should I set the SecurityManager, and how should I code the SecurityManager to ensure a secure app server.

Is SecurityManager the correct approach, or is there some other way to accomplish my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

It has been protected using Java Security Manager and system is configured with policies ,which do not allow such calls.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought. But how should I configure the Security Manager and policies? I tried with WSO2 Application Server on my own machine, it doesn't restrict such calls. Is there any document on that topic?